# Is it possible to use SAML V2 from Blazor WebAssembly App?

Tags: blazor, saml-2.0, blazor-webassembly, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I can use easily Itfoxtec libraries to authenticate in SAML on a Blazor Server App in .Net 6.

But I don't know how to get a Blazor WebAssembly App work for SAML.

I have tried to adapt some parts like builder.Services.AddRemoteAuthentication on webassembly client part but without any success. As Microsoft documentation says, OpenId Connect seems to be the only way of using Authentication Library from WebAssembly: [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with the Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Hence, is it finally possible to configure a Blazor WebAssembly App for SAML?

Comment: A part of answers is specific to SAML. SAML is not adapted to SPA. It is a limitation of SAML see: [https://www.identityserver.com/articles/why-you-wouldn-t-use-saml-in-a-spa-and-mobile-app](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/why-you-wouldn-t-use-saml-in-a-spa-and-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to secure a Blazor WebAssembly App with SAML 2.0.

You should use OpenID Connect instead. The best solution is to use an identity broker (like e.g. [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com/docs/)) to handle the SAML 2.0 communication and convert to OpenID Connect.